# python pandas: date/time function to compute time period

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have the following working code, trying to filter in the data within 14 days of the reference date. However, I had to hard code the date:

```
reference_ts = "2016-09-15 00:00:00"
df1 = df[df.my_ts >= "2016-09-01 00:00:00"]
```

I am wondering is there any function that I can use to compute a certain time period from a reference time point? Something like the pseudo code below:

```
df1 = df[df.my_ts >= date_sub(reference_ts,14)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: try using pandas `to_datetime` function and then you should be able to use a `datetime` object version of your reference to do any comparisons or processing you need. I'd strongly suggest trying something though.

Comment: Please provide a sample data set and desired / resulting data set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [pd.Timedelta()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html):

```
reference_ts = pd.to_datetime("2016-09-15 00:00:00")
df1 = df[df.my_ts >= reference_ts - pd.Timedelta(days=14)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

You can just check [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

It is gonna solve your problem.